# How To store data in sqlite from google signin

Tags: android, ajax, sqlite, cordova

I want to store user data in sqlite which i get from google signin , but i can print the whole data in alert box can unable to store it in the sqlite..here is the code

```
 $.ajax({
           url:'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token='+accessToken,
           type:'GET',
           data:term,
           dataType:'json',
           error:function(jqXHR,text_status,strError){
           },
           success:function(data)
           {
           var item;

           var simpleJson = JSON.stringify(data));
           alert(simpleJson); //alert is working here can see data in JSON format
            // Save the userprofile data in your sqlite.
            myDB.transaction(function (txe)
            {
                 txe.executeSql('CREATE TABLE User_data(id integer primary key, email text, name text, given_name text, family_name varchar, picture text, gender text, locale varchar)');
            });

            //here i am trying to store data in sqlite
            myDB.transaction(function (txe1) 
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < simpleJson.length; i++) 
                {

                    txe1.executeSql('INSERT INTO User_data (id,email,name,given_name,family_name,picture,gender,locale) VALUES  (' + simpleJson.[i].id + ' , "' + simpleJson.[i].email + '" , "' + simpleJson.[i].name + '", "' + simpleJson.[i].given_name + '","' + simpleJson.[i].family_name + '","' + simpleJson.[i].picture + '","' + simpleJson.[i].gender + '","' + simpleJson.[i].locale + '")', [],
                    function (tx, result) 
                    {
                        navigator.notification.alert('Registered successfully', null, 'Info', 'ok'); 
                    },
                    function (error) 
                    {
                        alert("invalied request " + error);
                    });
                }
            });
           }
           });
disconnectUser();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass values to database like this

```
/**
     * Insert content values to the specified table
     *
     * @param paramString        Table Name
     * @param paramContentValues Content Values
     * @return
     */
    public long insertContentVals(String paramString, ContentValues paramContentValues) {
        try {
            long l = this.db.insert(paramString, null, paramContentValues);
            return l;
        } catch (Exception localException) {
//            localException.printStackTrace();
            CommonUtilities._Log(CommonUtilities.logs.e, "Error", Log.getStackTraceString(localException));
        }
        return 0L;
    }
```

Comment: i am working on cordova not on native android, it wont work